# Evaluating area of $\frac{3}{4}$ of a disc

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

> Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2}xdx+x^2ydy$$
>
> Where
>
> $\gamma_1(t)=(2\cos t,2\sin t),t\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$
>
> $\gamma_2(t)=(\cos t,\sin t),t\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$
>
> Using Green's theorem

Visualising the curve it is a [there quarters disc](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20(2cost,2sint)%20and%20(cost,sint),%20t%3D-pi%2F2..pi)

So the curves will be as followed

$\gamma_a(t)=(0,1+t),t\in[0,1]$

$\gamma_1(t)=(2\cos t,2\sin t),t\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$

$\gamma_{b}(t)=(2-t,0),t\in[0,1]$

$\gamma_2(t)=(\cos t,\sin t),t\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$

Using Green's theorem

In the case of $\gamma_a(t)$ and $\gamma_b(t)$ both vanishes as $Q_y=2xy$ and once $x=0$ and once $y=0$ so the integrand vanishes

$$I_1=\int_{\gamma_1}xdx+x^2ydy=\int\int_{D} 2xy dx dy=\int_{0}^2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}(2\rho \cos \theta *\rho \sin \theta *\rho )d \theta d\rho=\\=\int_{0}^2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}(2\rho^3 \cos \theta\sin \theta)d \theta d\rho=\int_{0}^2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}(\rho^3 2\cos \theta\sin \theta)d \theta d\rho=\\=\int_{0}^2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}(\rho^3 \sin 2\theta)d \theta d\rho=\int_{0}^2\rho^3*(-\frac{\cos2\theta}{2}|_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi})d\rho=-\int_{0}^2\rho^3 d\rho=-4$$

The same happen to

$$I_2=-\int_{\gamma_2}xdx+x^2ydy=-\int_{0}^1\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}(2\rho^3 \cos \theta\sin \theta)d \theta d\rho=\int_{0}^1\rho^3 d\rho=1$$

So overall we have $-4+1=-3$ which is obviously wrong, what have I missed?

Which is obviously wrong, what have I missed?

Comment: Thanks! but I will still get $-\frac{15}{4}+1$

Comment: What are $\gamma_a, \gamma_b$ doing in this question?

Comment: I wanted to create a closed curve so I can use Green's theorem

Comment: Using Green's theorem need to the area be closed but $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2$ isn't close in the main question.

Comment: Also what's the orientation?

Comment: @user108128 I was asked to solve in by Green's theorem, Can I close it and the reduce that integrals of "added curves"? in this case it was $0$

Comment: @xbh anticlockwise

Comment: @gbox Umm, $\gamma_a, \gamma_b$ does not work here.

Comment: @xbh is wrong? or vanishes?

Comment: @gbox Both of them? In that case it's better to calculate directly.

Comment: @gbox $\gamma_a, \gamma_b, \gamma_1, \gamma_2$ do not determine a closed region.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81092/discussion-between-gbox-and-xbh).

Comment: @xbh why? all the is left is $y=[-2,-1]$ and $x=[-2,-1]$?

Comment: @gbox So there are typos in your post…?

Comment: @xbh I meant all that is left to close is...

Comment: @gbox Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let define

- $\gamma_3(t)=(-2+2t,0),t\in[0,1]$
- $\gamma_4(t)=(0,-2t),t\in[0,1]$
- $\gamma_5(t)=(-1+t,0),t\in[0,1]$
- $\gamma_6(t)=(0,-t),t\in[0,1]$

then we have

$$\int_{\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2}xdx+x^2ydy=\int_{\gamma_1\cup \gamma_3\cup \gamma_4}xdx+x^2ydy+\int_{\gamma_2\cup \gamma_5\cup \gamma_6}xdx+x^2ydy-\int_{\gamma_3}xdx+x^2ydy-\int_{\gamma_4}xdx+x^2ydy-\int_{\gamma_5}xdx+x^2ydy-\int_{\gamma_6}xdx+x^2ydy$$

and by Green theorem

$$\int_{\gamma_1\cup \gamma_3\cup \gamma_4}xdx+x^2ydy+\int_{\gamma_2\cup \gamma_5\cup \gamma_6}xdx+x^2ydy=\iint_{D_1} 2xy\,dx\,dy+\iint_{D_2}2xy\,dx\,dy$$

and by polar coordinates

$$\iint_{D_1}2xy\,dx\,dy=\int_{-\pi/2}^\pi d\theta \int_0^2 2\rho^3\cos \theta \sin \theta\, d\rho=-\frac14$$

$$\iint_{D_2}2xy\,dx\,dy=\int_{-\pi/2}^\pi d\theta \int_0^1 2\rho^3\cos \theta \sin \theta\, d\rho=-4$$

and

$$\int_{\gamma_3}xdx+x^2ydy=\int_{0}^{1} 2(-2+2t)dt=\left[-4t+2t^2\right]_{0}^{1}=-2$$

$$\int_{\gamma_4}xdx+x^2ydy=0$$

$$\int_{\gamma_5}xdx+x^2ydy=\int_{0}^{1} (-1+t)dt=\left[-t+\frac12 t^2\right]_{0}^{1}=-\frac12$$

$$\int_{\gamma_6}xdx+x^2ydy=0$$

therefore

$$\int_{\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2}xdx+x^2ydy=-\frac14-4+2+\frac12=\frac{-1-16+8+2}{4}=-\frac74$$

which is consistent with direct evaluation for

- [**integral 1**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20(-4sin%20t%20cos%20t%2B16cos%5E3t*sin%20t)dt,%20t%3D-pi%2F2..pi) $\int_{\gamma_1}xdx+x^2ydy=-2$
- [**integral 2**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20(-sin%20t%20cos%20t%2Bcos%5E3t*sin%20t)dt,%20t%3D-pi%2F2..pi) $\int_{\gamma_1}xdx+x^2ydy=\frac14$

Comment: Can not we use just $\gamma_a,\gamma_b$ as I did? you use two curves to describe describe a line?

Comment: @gbox I've made in that way to use Green theorem as requested, but of course we can also proceed in other equivalent ways.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider follwoing paths to close the area with positive directions

$\gamma_a(t)=(0,-1-t),t\in[0,1]$,

$\gamma_1(t)=(2\cos t,2\sin t),t\in [-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\pi]$,

$\gamma_{b}(t)=(-2+t,0),t\in[0,1]$,

$\gamma_2(t)=(\cos t,\sin t),t\in [-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\pi]$.

Now use direct way with path $\gamma_a+\gamma_1+\gamma_b-\gamma_2$. With Green's theorem
$$\int_1^2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}2 r^3\ \sin t\cos t\ dt\ dr=\color{blue}{-\dfrac{15}{4}}$$

---

**Edit:** Details in direct way are
$$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_a}=\int_0^10d0+0dt=0$$
$$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_1}=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}-4\sin t\cos t+16\sin t\cos^3 t\ dt=-2$$
$$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_b}=\int_0^1(-2+t)\ dt=-\dfrac32$$
$$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_2}=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}-\sin t\cos t+\sin t\cos^3 t\ dt=\dfrac14$$
these conclude $0+(-2)+(-\dfrac32)-(\dfrac14)=\color{blue}{-\dfrac{15}{4}}$

Comment: $\gamma_a,\gamma_b$ vanishes and $\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2$ is $\int_1^2\int_\frac{-pi}{2}^\pi sr^3 \sin t\cos t dt dr$?

Comment: Nah. Only $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_a}=0$ .

Comment: But, we have $Pdx=x, Qdy=x^2y$ so $Q_x-P_y=2xy-0$ and on $\gamma_b$, $y=0$

And how can the area be negative?

Comment: With green we don't use pathes, only in direct way we need to replace $x$ and $y$ with parametrizations.

Comment: and in green we need the area of integration to specify our bounds.

Comment: I do not see how I calculate $\int_{\gamma_{b}}$ just a simple line integral? not by green?

Comment: with $\gamma_b$, $y=0$ so it's $\int_0^1 xdx=\int_0^1 (-2+t)dt=-\dfrac32$

Comment: So it is $-\frac{15}{4}--\frac{3}{2}=-\frac{9}{4}$

Comment: Why not? the curve we want in the end is without those two lines we add to create a closed curve

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_a}=\int_0^10d0+0dt=0$, right?

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_1}=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}(-4\sin t\cos t+16\sin t\cos^3 t)\ dt=-2$, right?

Comment: We are looking for$ \int_{\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2}xdx+x^2ydy$ then the result should be $-2+\frac14=-\frac74$

Comment: OP wants to use green theorem, then the area should be closed.

Comment: @user108128 $\int_{\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2}xdx+x^2ydy$ isthe integral along two lines, that is equal to $\int_{\gamma_1}xdx+x^2ydy+\int_{\gamma_2}xdx+x^2ydy$, to evaluate that we can consider a closed path which contains those lines and apply Green theorem.

Comment: Read the question again, over!

Comment: @user108128 The question states $\int_{\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2}xdx+x^2ydy$ using Green theorem and $\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2$ is not coled. Thus, in mine interpretation, we need to close the area, apply Green theorem and subtract the line integral added.

Comment: @gimusi correct

Comment: then the answer is $\dfrac{-15}{4}-\dfrac{-3}{2}=-\dfrac94$.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong in the limits of the outer integral. It should be from 1 to 2 therefore:$$\int_{1}^{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}r^3\sin2\theta d\theta dr=\int_{1}^{2}-r^3dr=-\dfrac{15}{4}$$